# making a link with a specific id visible

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a list of items from Question model on each users profile page /views/users/show.html.erb in a Rails app. The list of items is kind of information that you'd expect to find in  in /views/questions/index.html.erb. I've arranged it so that when a user clicks on the show link, it displays the content in the same page /views/users/show.html/. If the user clicks on another show link, it just replaces the content that was displayed with the id of the question that was clicked with the next link.  However, after the user clicks on show, there's no way to unclose the data, unless the user refreshes the home page etc; therefore, once a user clicks on a show link (let's say there's a list of 10 links), I want to be able to display a link beside the entry that was clicked (as opposed to the 9 in the list that weren't) that allows the user to hide the data. I know how to hide the data (i.e. it would just be a link back to the same page), however, I don't know how to make the link appear beside the entry that was clicked. I've given each link a unique class id using the id of the question, so i can differentiate between the links, but I'm stuck on where to go from here. Can you please suggest what I might do?

```
<td><%= link_to "Show", {:controller => 'users', :action =>'show', :question_id =>"#{question.id}"}, {:class => "question #{question.id}"}%></td>
```

[image]

Update. I can't put a hide link beside every item, and then set visibility to 'hidden', so I just need a way to set the css to visible of the hide link corresponding to the show link that was clicked.

Update, when I click on the show link (say for question 24), it provides this information in the currentTarget attribute

```
currentTarget: a.question 24

http://localhost:3000/users/28?question_id=24
```

Therefore, I'd need to make visible a link with the class "close 24." Is there a regular expression that I can use to make sure I get the id and only the id from the currentTarget?

```
showHide: function(e){

      e.currentTarget

      $('close' + id ).css('visibility', 'visible')

    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your links, you can add a data attributes for the question id

```
link_to 'text', url, data: { qid: question.id }
```

then in your js

```
showHide: function(e) {
  $('.close' + e.currentTarget.data('qid')).css('visibility', 'visible')
}
```